# Django-ratings : 'RatingField' object has no attribute 'add'

Tags: python, django, django-ratings

I tried using the example that they gave on the documentation of this app.

Their example:
And adding votes is also simple:
`Ubicacion.rating.add(score=1, user=request.user, ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])`

but it returns me this error:

```
 'RatingField' object has no attribute 'add'
```

And I did look up in the fields.py of the app, and indeed there is a function "add"

So I don't know why when I create the object of that class doesn't recognize the attributes of that class?

This is my model:

```
class Ubicacion(models.Model):
route = models.LineStringField()
coordsdet = models.LineStringField()
fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User)
objects = models.GeoManager()
rating = RatingField(range=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with `django-ratings`, but it looks like you should be calling the `rating.add` on an instance of your `Ubicacion` class- not on the class itself.

First create an instance:

```
myinstance = Ubicacion.objects.create(...)
```

Then, according to the `django-ratings` docs you could call `add`:

```
myinstance.rating.add(score=1, user=request.user, ip_address=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```